# TTS Discord Bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot but in TTS command I tried to run it but it doesn't work with this code (I have installed  `npm i discord-tts` ) so I tried everything to make it work but it doesn't, I wanted to know that did I missed something?

```
const discordTTS = require("discord-tts");
const Command = require('../Command.js');


module.exports = class SpeakCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'speak',
            usage: 'speak <message>',
            description: 'Speaks TTS message.',
            type: client.types.FUN
        });
    }

    async run(message, args) {

        function tts(voiceChannel, text) {
            const broadcast = bot.voice.createBroadcast();
            var channelId = message.member.voice.channelID;
            var channel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId);
            channel.join().then(connection => {
            broadcast.play(discordTTS.getVoiceStream(args));
            const dispatcher = connection.play(broadcast);

            });

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You only wrote the function.
Call the function and fill the params.